# There are any possibilities to replace delegate in the view using QML?

Tags: model-view-controller, qt, delegates, model, qml

For example

```
 ListView {
     id: listView
     anchors.fill: parent
     anchors.margins: 20
     model: myModel
     delegate: myDelegate
     highlightFollowsCurrentItem: true
     focus: true
     ListModel {
         id: myModel

         ListElement {
             name: "Apple"; cost: 2.45
             attributes: [
                 ListElement { description: "Core" },
                 ListElement { description: "Deciduous" }
             ]
         isOnMouse: false
     }
 }
```

I use myDelegate as default for any model, but if one of the item is clicked i whant to use another delegate for this item, only for this item.

Is it possible?

Comment: I've answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784706/selecting-delegates-depending-on-property. Perhaps it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the QML [`Loader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) element as your delegate, then you should be able to change its `source` or `sourceComponent`, effectively changing your delegate for a single item.

Answer (score 1):

In your main item define:

```
property boolean isItem:false
```

in your delegate make:

`onClicked: isItem=index==myIndex`  where myIndex descripe your special item

in the listView set :

```
delegate: isItem? otherDel : myDelegate
```

Comment: This does not answer the question because it changes the delegate for all items rather than only the delegate for the clicked item.