# selecting delegates depending on property

Tags: qt, delegates, qml

I have a listview where I want to use either a defaultDelegate or a customDelegate depending on the value of a property.
So far I've tried using a component to load the different delegates:

```
 Component{
    id: delegate
    Loader {
        sourceComponent: type == 3 ? customDelegate : defaultDelegate
    }
}
```

However, I can't access the properties I have in my model from the two delegates I have. I have the following error:

```
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

Here is the model I use:

```
ListModel {
     id: test
     ListElement {
         name: "Bill"
         team: "554"
         type: 2
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "John"
         team: "555"
         type: 3
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "Sam"
         team: "556"
         type: 1
     }
 }
```

Does anyone Have any idea, what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, of course, a context problem. In your code, the `name`, `team` and `type` context properties inserted by the `ListView` into `delegate`'s context is inaccessible to the components inside your delegates, as the `Loader` uses the creation context of `customDelegate` and `defaultDelegate` as the parent context when instantiating them, and `name`, `team` and `type` do not refer to anything withing that context chain.
One solution is to explicitly set the required information as a property of the `Loader` (this works because the `Loader` sets itself as the context object for the component it is loading).

Following a working example:

```
ListModel {
     id: testModel
     ListElement {
         name: "Bill"
         team: "554"
         type: 2
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "John"
         team: "555"
         type: 3
     }
     ListElement {
         name: "Sam"
         team: "556"
         type: 1
     }
 }

ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: testModel

    delegate: myDelegate
}

Component {
    id: myDelegate // yourDelegate
    Loader {
        property string modelName: model.name
        property string modelTeam: model.team
        property int modelType: model.type
        sourceComponent: modelType === 3 ? colonDelegate : semicolonDelegate
    }
}

Component {
    id: colonDelegate
    Text { text: modelName + ": " + modelTeam }
}

Component {
    id: semicolonDelegate
    Text { text: modelName + "; " + modelTeam }
}
```

For further reading and improvements I highly recommend you to read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#using-a-loader-within-a-view-delegate742,d.cWc).

Comment: thank you. I just assumed the loader would pass the model to the  two delegates.